# Laravel excel multiple sheet con diferentes tablas

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desarrollando reportes con Laravel Excel, hasta el momento no tenia problemas pero empece a utilizarlo con multiples sheets y pues carga todo correctamente pero esta vez quisiera que en cada hoja este una tabla diferente con diferente contenido a la tabla de la anterior hoja.

Archivo Export:

```
public function view(): View
    {
        return view('ReporteGeneral.index', [
            'excel' => Personal::Reporte_Familia('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31'),
            'excel2' => Personal::Reporte_PuestoTrabajo('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31'),
            'excel3' => Personal::Reporte_Ubicacion('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31'),
            'titulo' => $this->titulo
        ]);
    }

    public function title(): string
    {   
        return $this->titulo;
    }
```

Vista donde cargan los datos:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cabezera 1</td>
        <td>Cabezera 2</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($excel as $e1)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$e1->dato1}}</td>
        <td>{{$e1->dato2}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cabezera 1</td>
        <td>Cabezera 2</td>
        <td>Cabezera 3</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($excel2 as $e2)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$e2->dato1}}</td>
        <td>{{$e2->dato2}}</td>
        <td>{{$e2->dato3}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cabezera 1</td>
        <td>Cabezera 2</td>
        <td>Cabezera 3</td>
        <td>Cabezera 4</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($excel3 as $e3)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$e3->dato1}}</td>
        <td>{{$e3->dato2}}</td>
        <td>{{$e3->dato3}}</td>
        <td>{{$e3->dato4}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Me gustaria que cada variable carge en una nueva vista (hoja) y que todos conformen un mismo archivo excel pero no se como hacer que eso suceda, que salte a la siguiente pagina. No se mucho sobre laravel excel, necesito apoyo por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes echarle un vistazo a la documentación, específicamente a la parte de [multiple-sheets](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/multiple-sheets.html). Si cada vista es un reporte diferente, entonces deberías manejarlo de esta manera, basándome en la última versión `3.1`:

Si cada hoja es distinta, entonces debes crear una hoja por reporte.

En tu caso, si quieres un reporte para Familia, Puestos y Ubicación, entonces necesitas tres clases `Sheet`. Como notarás, también necesitas tres vistas (`view`) distintas, para cada clase.

Para `Familias`:

```
namespace App\Exports\Sheets;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class ReporteFamiliaSheet implements FromView, WithTitle
{
    public function view(): View
    {
       return view('reporte.familia', [
           'familias' => Familia::all()
       ]);
    }


    public function title(): string
    {
        return 'reporte-familia';
    }
}
```

Para `Puestos`:

```
namespace App\Exports\Sheets;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class ReportePuestosSheet implements FromView, WithTitle
{
    public function view(): View
    {
       return view('reporte.puestos', [
           'puestos' => Puestos::all()
       ]);
    }


    public function title(): string
    {
        return 'reporte-puestos';
    }
}
```

Una vez tengas todas tus hojas listas, pasas a crear la clase de exportación, y agregas cada hoja que creaste anteriormente:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class ReporteGeneralExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];
        // Agregas las hojas
        array_push($sheets, new ReporteFamiliaSheet());
        array_push($sheets, new ReportePuestosSheet());
        array_push($sheets, new ReporteUbicacionesSheet());

        return $sheets;
    }
}
```

Finalmente, procedes a descargar el archivo excel con las hojas.

```
public function download() 
{
    return (new ReporteGeneralExport())->download('reporte-general.xlsx');
}
```

Es un ejemplo práctico, espero que puedas adecuarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias me sirvio! Es que recien estoy que uso laravel excel y no sabia sobre este tema.